# Drawing points in real time (or at short intervals) using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt5

I’m working on a robot that moves in space and transfers its GPS coordinates to the server. I need to create a script in QGIS that will receive coordinates and draw points based on these coordinates in real time. I have a script that draws points from a list and I know how to make a client that will receive coordinates from the server. But I don’t know how to make a script that will work constantly and in real time draw the received coordinates (or work cyclically and draw points at a small interval, this solution will also work).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can use Python to pull in the coordinates every second etc. Which program does your robot run on ?
Perhaps there is a python module for it?